# How to add new attributes to map in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

My database structure,

```
{
  "email":"example@mail.com",
  "products": {
    "product1":{
      "price":"$10",
      "details":"detail"
    },
    "product2":{
      "price":"$20",
      "details":"detail"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add new attributes to "products" map and expected output as follow,

```
{
  "email":"example@mail.com",
  "products": {
    "product1":{
      "price":"$10",
      "details":"detail"
    },
    "product2":{
      "price":"$20",
      "details":"detail"
    },
    "product3":{
      "price":"$10",
      "details":"detail"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using API Gateway and UpdateItem action. Here is my mapping template,

```
{
    "TableName": "tableName",
    "Key": {
        "email": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.email')"
        }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "SET #pr = :vals",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#pr": "products"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":vals": {
            "M": {
                "$input.path('$.productId')": {
                    "M": {
                        "price": {
                            "N": "$input.path('$.price')"
                        },
                        "details": {
                            "S": "$input.path('$.details')"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "ReturnValues": "NONE"
}
```

Using above template will replace all my attributes. Actual output,

```
{
  "email":"example@mail.com",
  "products": {
    "product3":{
      "price":"$10",
      "details":"detail"
    }
  }
}
```

How I can add new attributes to map instead of replace it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your request you are `SET`ting the entire Products map, but you only want to add a nested map.

```
{
    "TableName": "tableName",
    "Key": {
        "email": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.email')"
        }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "SET #pr.product3 = :vals",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#pr": "products"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":vals": {
            "M": {
                "$input.path('$.productId')": {
                    "M": {
                        "price": {
                            "N": "$input.path('$.price')"
                        },
                        "details": {
                            "S": "$input.path('$.details')"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "ReturnValues": "NONE"
}
```